# Status bar in google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to make a status bar in the top of this map
Like this: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geolocate/geolocate.html
Can you show me how to do that, thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just start with the code from that map you like, since it does what you want? Save the HTML file (HTML only) and make sure it works, then tweak it up from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE xhtml PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Where Am I?</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="geometa.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  *, html { margin:0; padding:0 }
  div#map_canvas { width:100%; height:100%; }
  div#info { width:100%; position:absolute; overflow:hidden; text-align:center; top:0;
    left:0; }
  .lightBox {
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    -moz-opacity:0.6;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.6;
    opacity: 0.6;
    background-color:white;
    padding:2px;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  function initialise() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    prepareGeolocation();
    doGeolocation();
  }

  function doGeolocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionSuccess, positionError);
    } else {
      positionError(-1);
    }
  }

  function positionError(err) {
    var msg;
    switch(err.code) {
      case err.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        msg = "Unable to find your location";
        break;
      case err.PERMISSION_DENINED:
        msg = "Permission denied in finding your location";
        break;
      case err.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
        msg = "Your location is currently unknown";
        break;
      case err.BREAK:
        msg = "Attempt to find location took too long";
        break;
      default:
        msg = "Location detection not supported in browser";
    }
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = msg;
  }

  function positionSuccess(position) {
    // Centre the map on the new location
    var coords = position.coords || position.coordinate || position;
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude);
    map.setCenter(latLng);
    map.setZoom(12);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latLng,
        title: 'Why, there you are!'
    });
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 'Looking for <b>' +
        coords.latitude + ', ' + coords.longitude + '</b>...';

    // And reverse geocode.
    (new google.maps.Geocoder()).geocode({latLng: latLng}, function(resp) {
              var place = "You're around here somewhere!";
          if (resp[0]) {
              var bits = [];
          for (var i = 0, I = resp[0].address_components.length; i < I; ++i) {
              var component = resp[0].address_components[i];
              if (contains(component.types, 'political')) {
                  bits.push('<b>' + component.long_name + '</b>');
                }
            }
            if (bits.length) {
                place = bits.join(' > ');
            }
            marker.setTitle(resp[0].formatted_address);
        }
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = place;
      });
  }

  function contains(array, item) {
      for (var i = 0, I = array.length; i < I; ++i) {
              if (array[i] == item) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialise()">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  <div id="info" class="lightbox">Detecting your location...</div>
</body>
</html>
```